# How to use GraphQL?

Tags: python-3.x, graphql-js, graphene-python

I start a tutorial to install graphql with python(graphene). But there is a step I can't reach because I don't know how I can reach it.
Here's the [link](https://docs.graphene-python.org/en/latest/quickstart/). After installing Python, pip, GraphQL, WHERE can I write the code to creating a basic schema ?? I have spyder as IDE to code in python but otherwise I don't have anything else, and they don't give any hint to reach this step...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a big question, given what you're wanting to do. You should familiarize yourself with basic python project work before approaching this.

I'd suggest going through a tutorial or two regarding the use of modules. One I'd recommend is the free How to Think Like a Computer Scientist. The working with modules section begins at https://runestone.academy/runestone/static/thinkcspy/PythonModules/toctree.html

Working with GraphQL implies that you have some larger project or framework that you'll be working within. Is that the case here?

If you are just starting out, I'd highly recommend the above course, or another. Google, for instance, has a great intro at https://developers.google.com/edu/python/introduction.

If you aren't tied to Spyder, I might suggest you consider VSCode, which is a great IDE for beginners as well as advanced coders. They have a good intro to working with Python at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial.

Forgive me if I've misunderstood your skill level and familiarity.